# Why am I getting AnnotationConfiguration instance is required when AnnotationConfiguration is deprecated?

Tags: java, hibernate

Using Hibernate 4.2.6 and Spring 3.1.1

I have one class similar to this

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "MY_TABLE" )
public class MyTable{ ... }
```

Then I have the following in my hibernate.cfg.xml file

```
<mapping class="com.mycompany.myapp.persistence.domain.MyTable"/>
```

When I run a JUnit test where I get a Session and query the table, I get the following error:

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingException: An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use <mapping class="com.mycompany.myapp.persistence.domain.MyTable"/>
```

I don't understand why when, based on what I've read, AnnotationConfiguration is deprecated and functionality moved into Configuration.

To get the Session, I'm doing this

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.configure();
ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();        
sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
```

but it's unable to get the Session and throws this error.

Comment: Oh... Don't I at least need to specify the db driver, url, etc. in the xml? Do I not even need this <mapping class=...> bit?

Comment: Well, if I remove that, then the AnnotationConfiguration error goes away, but it doesn't get a session. I now get an error, "Configured SessionFactory: null." Is there any problem with the code that starts with Configuration configuration = new Configuration(): ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be working now. Solution was twofold:

**First**, this code is correct:

a) mapping class remains in the hibernate.cfg.xml

b) Create a HibernateUtil Class

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure();
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();        
            return configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

c) Create the Model class

d) Then in the test, instantiate the sessionFactory in the setup() like this

```
sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
```

e) Then query the database like this

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
List<TableName> result = session.createQuery("from table").list();
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
```

**Second,** I was using JBoss 4.2 as my targeted runtime, which was using Hibernate 3.4.2, before this AnnotatedConfiguration class was deprecated. Not targeting JBoss as a runtime results in using Hibernate 4.2.6 (imported via Maven) and not causing this error. Should've paid better attention as Hibernate prints its version when it sets up! :-)