# AnnotationsCongifuration in web application using jsp,hibernate,mysql and eclipse mars

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, hibernate, jsp

I am using eclipse Mars to create a dynamic web application with Hibernate and Jsp. I am getting an error

```
 An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use <mapping class="com.hibernate.bean.User"/>
error
```

This is the [link](http://www.javawebtutor.com/articles/hibernate/hibernate_web_example.php) of the code which I used in my program. Refer this link to see the code

Can anyone solve my problem?

thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Lorg/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor;I)
(…)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
ContainerBase.addChild:
start: LifecycleException:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Lorg/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor;I)
```

Now i am getting these type of exception

Comment: Google is your friend: https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-error-an-annotationconfiguration-instance-is-required-to-use/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting AnnotationConfiguration instance is required when AnnotationConfiguration is deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038907/why-am-i-getting-annotationconfiguration-instance-is-required-when-annotationcon)

Comment: Here I didn't use @ID or any annotation, In the above link they used annotations

Comment: Well you need to post your code because otherwise, how are we supposed to know you didn't use annotations? Your exception is about annotations so it's a fair assumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed adding jar files for hibernate. Now I cleared all my exceptions.I got the answer from this [website](http://www.hildeberto.com/2008/05/hibernate-and-jersey-conflict-on-glassfish.html).